# Recommended pattern to fetch data from API's in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

We are writing dash board app in React that requires us to fetch data from remote API's asynchronously. Until data s fetched, dashboard widgets need to show a hour glass or something similar. Using hooks, using Redux/Saga, using a local data access service are some of the approaches we considered. We are mostly biased towards using Redux/Saga for this but want to check if there are any standard/recommended patterns used by react community.

Comment: Since you are using redux, it might be worth looking into [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), it's opinionated but the opinions are amazing.

Comment: `use-http's` **useFetch** is quite helpful with less abstraction and more clarity: Here is the reference doc for it: [https://use-http.com/#/]

Answer (score 0):

Recent days I've seen these two libraries circling around community posts, haven't tried them myself, but maybe will be useful to your project:

https://github.com/zeit/swr

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query